# Using getattr with Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
class idDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self,key):
        return 'dsaads'
d=idDict()
print d['ss']
```

I just get an error: `KeyError: 'ss'`. According to some online forums, this should work.
I want to print out 'dsaads'

This doesn't work either; I get the same error:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class idDict(defaultdict):
    def __getattr__(self,key):
        return 'dsaads'
d=idDict()
print d['ss']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__):

```
>>> class idDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return 'dsaads'

>>> d=idDict()
>>> d['a']
'dsaads'

>>> help(dict.__getitem__)

Help on method_descriptor:

__getitem__(...)
    x.__getitem__(y) <==> x[y]
```

Answer (score 9):

`__getattr__()` is for attributes, not indexing. But `dict` already supports indexing, and you have no value for that key. Perhaps you're looking for [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead.